# Customize amchart zoom in/out buttons icon color

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

I am customizing the background (normal, down, and hover states) of the zoom in and zoom out buttons in an amcharts map chart in the following way:

```
let zoomControl = chart.set('zoomControl', am5map.ZoomControl.new(root, {}));

[zoomControl.minusButton, zoomControl.plusButton].forEach((button) => {
    button.get('background').setAll({
      cornerRadiusTL: 0,
      cornerRadiusTR: 0,
      cornerRadiusBR: 0,
      cornerRadiusBL: 0,
      fill: am5.color(0xe3e3e3),
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
    });

    button
      .get('background')
      .states.create('hover', {})
      .setAll({
        fill: am5.color(0xc7c7c7),
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
      });

    button
      .get('background')
      .states.create('down', {})
      .setAll({
        fill: am5.color(0xc7c7c7),
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
      });   
});
```

I am able in this way to get the background of the `+` and `-` icons a light gray. However the font-color of the `+` and `-` icons remains white. I would like to turn them black. How can this be achieved?